# Cannot activate yarn

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces, yarn-v2

I'm following [yarn installation doc](https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/install). When I run `corepack prepare yarn@stable --activate`, I'm getting `Usage Error: Invalid package manager specification in CLI arguments; expected a semver version`. Anyone know what's up?

Comment: If you have nodejs installed install it with npm
`npm i --location=global yarn`

Comment: But I do have yarn since my nodejs version is >16.10 and `yarn -v` shows 3.2.3.

Comment: Check what version of yarn your projects use yarn 1 is classic and new versions use plug and play..

Comment: I'm using the new version. I had to specify the semvar in command as `corepack prepare yarn@3.2.3 --activate` instead of putting `@stable` for it to work but it's bit weird that what official documentation says doesn't work. I was wondering if this is occurring to just me or everyone else.

Comment: @passionateLearner Thanks for posting this! Facing the same problem right now.

Answer (score 0):

As per this github issue https://github.com/yarnpkg/berry/issues/4132, you should `corepack enable` instead of `corepack prepare`